# Dotnet nuke Code Behind Event is not Executing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dotnetnuke

I have Existing Module, in which I have modified one User Control that contains some HTML Data. That is showing fine on my page.

Now, I want to execute Button Click Event. My Code is as below.

```
User Control .ascx Page
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="BrownBagMarketing.Modules.Maytronics.ViewMaytronics"
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ViewMaytronics.ascx.cs" %>

..... HTML Code....

<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkViewAll" Text="View All" runat="server" onclick="lnkViewAll_Click">
</asp:LinkButton>



---- User Control Code Behind .ascx.cs Page
namespace BrownBagMarketing.Modules.Maytronics
{
    public partial class ViewMaytronics : PortalModuleBase
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                //Response.Write("Test Event......");   
            }
        }
        protected void lnkViewAll_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

        }


    }
}
```

Even When I am Showing Response.write is Executing or not in a page load event, but it is not executing. My Other HTML part of the page is showing fine when I remove onclick event of link button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right now I am going with following code. but not get my exact answer.

can any one solve the issue so that i would not write the code on code behind page.

```
<script runat="server">
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        dlFeatures.DataSource = ClsProduct.GetAllFeatures();
        dlFeatures.DataBind();
    }
    //Response.Write("abc123458");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What module are you modifying? Is it a "wap" module (web application project) meaning that it is compiled into a DLL? If so, you will need to recompile after you make your codebehind changes.

Comment: It's not a wap Module. It is a custom module which contains some html content like product detail.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your ascx references your codebehind file - double check the names.

ASCX Example:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="QuizBackend.ascx.cs" Inherits="Bonitas.SalesRepQuiz.QuizBackend" %>
```

Code behind

```
namespace Bonitas.SalesRepQuiz
{
   public partial class QuizBackend : PortalModuleBase
   {
        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            btnYourButton.Click += btnYourButton_Click;
        }

        protected void btnYourButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // Your code
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Exceptions.ProcessModuleLoadException(this, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```